# Unable to knit R program (there is no package called 'backports'

Tags: r

I am new to R. Its says there is no package called backports. I tried installing package called backports and loading it but it's not getting installed. And I am not able to see  mark down in HTML format. I am using Rstudio.

This is what I am getting as an error everytime I click on Knit:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :        there is no package called 'backports'
>   Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution halted**

If I do `install.package("backports")`, I am getting this

> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got this issue. It seems there is some problem with the CRAN source for this package. I installed the binary version from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backports/index.html and it worked.

Comment: I just tried downloading Windows binaries r-devel: backports_1.1.1.zip from the link you provided and installing it but its not working either.         
    Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. You just saved my day.